# How to analyse Heap memory in ruby

Tags: ruby, memory, garbage-collection, runtime, heap-memory

I am updating some environment variables which could change the ruby's heap memory allocation constants. After that I want to see the updated changes.
How to see the updated heap changes before and after setting environment variables?

```
RUBY_FREE_MIN : 1220000
RUBY_GC_HEAP_GROWTH_FACTOR : 1.9
RUBY_GC_MALLOC_LIMIT : 2000000000
RUBY_HEAP_MIN_SLOTS : 20000000
RUBY_HEAP_SLOTS_INCREMENT : 20000000
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since this is a broad question, I'll point you to some links:

https://tenderlovemaking.com/2017/09/27/visualizing-your-ruby-heap.html

https://github.com/srawlins/allocation_stats

https://www.sitepoint.com/ruby-uses-memory/

https://blog.codeship.com/the-definitive-guide-to-ruby-heap-dumps-part-i/